# Switch case for Custom field on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Im doing a Wordpress website have used Custom Field for the funtion.
I trying found the solution but cannot found idea to handle it/
This funtion is show info on Custom field.
I'm example a code show Sex:

With Custom Field Multi Select 'sex' have value:

```
      's0' => 'Not required',
      's1' => 'Male,',
      's2' => 'Female',
```

and code:

```
        <?php $getsex= get_field('sex');
    $arraysex[$getsex] = array('s0','s1','s2');
    switch ($arraysex) {
        case $arraysex[0] && $arraysex[1]:
            echo "Male";
            break;
        case $arraysex[0] && $arraysex[2]:
            echo "Female";
            break;
        case $arraysex[0] &&  $arraysex[1] && $arraysex[2]:
            echo "Both";
            break;
            }
    ?>
```

I want when MultiSelect on Backend wp-admin is Selects "Not required" & "Male" then its only display "Male" on frontend, Select "Not reqired" & "Female" its only dislay "Female"  on frontend, etc the same. I think my code incorrect.

Comment: Why would you allow multiple select in the first place?

Comment: I need to filter information and display for on front-end.

Here is code i'm using:

<code>
<?php $getsex = get_field('sex'); 
$arraysex = array(
    's0' => 'Not required,',
    's1' => 'Male,',
    's2' => 'Female',
  );
  
  foreach ($getsex as $value) {
  ?> 
  <?php echo $array[$value] ?> <?php } ?>

but it will display is : "Not required, Male,". I want display only "Male" on frontend when i multi select in backend is "s0 & s1"